# Read line from 2 files and print values of both files in one line shell script

Tags: text-processing

Need help for unix shell script.
I have 2 files:

file1:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

file2:

```
123
456
789
```

I need output as below:

```
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
```

Request you to please help asap

Comment: Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734976/edit) the question and add the script you currently have, and its output. Please use the code brackets `{code}` around the script for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to pair up the line of `file1` and `file2`, use `paste` with a space as delimiter:

```bash
$ paste -d ' ' file1 file2
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
```

Without the `-d` option and its argument, `paste` would use a tab character as the delimiter between the columns.

```bash
$ paste file1 file2
abc     123
def     456
ghi     789
```

This all assumes that the number of lines is the same in both files.